# Is there quantum error correction code package for python

Tags: error-correction, qutip

I'm working on the development of a new quantum error correction protocol that tries to maximize the coherence of the qubit. Is there a package for python, similar to qutip, that could help me in this process?

Comment: Also STIM maybe useful for you: https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that [Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/) might be able to help -  it is an open source python library that has loads of different features including allowing you to write quantum circuits and run them on real quantum backends. There are some examples of performing quantum error correction using Qiskit in [the textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/error-correction-repetition-code.html).

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out [Quaec](https://github.com/cgranade/python-quaec), documentation [here](https://www.cgranade.com/python-quaec/), which is:

> QuaEC is a library for working with quantum error correction, including support for efficiently maniuplating Pauli and Clifford operators.

The use of this would pretty much be as-is, since it is not actively (or even passively I believe) developed anymore.